# Need Help in ServiceStack SQL Expression for List<ServiceResponse> strList

Tags: c#, android, web-services, sqlite, ormlite-servicestack

I need the help in C# ORMLite servicestack webservice using SQLite database. In which I am sending the one string field 'Code' and getting the matched data from two tables.

I am facing the error in  SQL Expression under Db.SqlList("Sql Query").

Actually I am expecting multiple records in Response in a List as return value.

Please help me out how the fill the List as return from SQLExpression under ServiceStack webservice. I do not want to use entity framework for SQl queries.

### Database Table

```
Table 1
{
    int ID,
    string Field1 
}

Table 2
{
    int ID,
    int LinkId ,
    string Field2,
    string code
}
```

### Sample Code

```
[Route("/CodeStatus/{Code}",  Verbs = "GET")]
public class CodeStatus : IReturn<ServiceResponse>
{
    //public int DeviceStatusID { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

// Service Response

```
public class ServiceResponse
{ 
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}

public class CodeStatusService : Service
{

    CrudFunctions<CodeStatus> _crud;

    public object ANY(CodeStatus request)
    {
        return Crud.AskForStatus(request.ConvertTo<CodeStatus>());
    } 
}

public class CrudFunctions<T>
{ 

    public IDbConnection Db { get; private set; }

    public CrudFunctions(IDbConnection db)
    {
        Db = db;
    }

    // Check the multiple data as per 'Code' in Table 2 

    public object AskForStatus(CodeStatus request)
    {
            // ERROR While executing the query..
        List<ServiceResponse> strList =   Db.SqlList<ServiceResponse>
("SELECT PD.Field1 As Field1, BD.Field2 AS Field2 lsId FROM Table1 T1 JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.Id  = T2.LinkId WHERE T2.Code = " + request.Code);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't concatenate string values to a raw SQL Statement directly, at a minimum they need to be in quotes, but they should also be escaped to avoid SQL Injection attacks. You can do this by changing your Input variables to db parameters, e.g:

```
var strList =  Db.SqlList<ServiceResponse>(
    @"SELECT PD.Field1 As Field1, BD.Field2 AS Field2 lsId 
        FROM Table1 T1 JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.Id  = T2.LinkId 
       WHERE T2.Code = @Code", new { request.Code });
```